# Is there way to round str (special case)?

Tags: python, string, rounding

So I need to output a txt file that in one row contains the city-value of all companies in said industry rounded on 2 decimal places. Code works as intended I just need to round them to 2 decimal places. I have some guesses in what seems to be a problem with rounding them but I just can't figure it out. PS I'm new to python and coding in general so I'm sorry if my question seems dumb.

```
import os

try:
    import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
    os.system("pip install pandas")


def main(filename='statups.csv'):
    # reading the csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # grouping by industry name and city and summing the value
    ast = df.groupby(['Industry', 'City'], as_index=False)['Valuation 
    ($B)'].sum()
    # sorting the columns
    ast = ast.sort_values(by=['Industry', 'Valuation ($B)'], ascending= 
    [True, False])

# could have done with pandas but ran into saving group by to csv function error
# and went with inefficient way

    # creating the dictionary to hold each industry value
    my_dict = {}
    for val in ast['Industry'].unique():
        val = val.replace(" ", '_')
        my_dict[val] = []

# storing the value in dictionary
   for index, row in ast.iterrows():
       val = row['Industry'].replace(" ", '_')
       my_dict[val].append(str(row['City']) + "-" + str(row['Valuation 
       ($B)']))

# saving the value from the dictionary
   for k in my_dict.keys():
      with open(f'{k} + ".txt", 'w') as textfile:
          for element in my_dict[k]:
              textfile.write('{:0.3f}'.format(element) + "\n")         
if __name__ == '__main__':
   filename = input('Enter filename: ')
   main(filename)
```

Comment: `with open(f'{k} + ".txt", 'w') as textfile:`  - mismatching " or ' - also why add a string to an interpolated string:  `with open(f'{k}.txt' , 'w') as textfile:` works

Comment: Can you please explain what are you meaning by mismatching 'or'? English is not my first language so I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of that part of the sentence.

Comment: Look at the color coding of your code. You see that strings are green. Look at your last 5 or so lines. They are mostly green - because in some line you are missing a " or ' to end that lines string. `with open(f'{k} + ".txt", 'w') as textfile:` has an opening `'` that is not closed by your code.

Comment: ohhh i see now what you have meant ty so much